# How to embed a Django website in external iframe

Tags: django, reactjs, iframe

I would like to embed my Django website in a specific external website (not any website).

For example, my website is https://www.mywebsite.com and would like to include it in an other website (https://www.example.com) with an iframe like this:

```
<iframe 
    src="https://www.mywebsite.com">
</iframe>
```

I read a lot of docs and I don't understand if I have to use django-csp or X_FRAME_OPTIONS (which seems depreciated), or both to be compatible with every navigators.

I tried to install and setup django-csp but in that case all of the ressources are blocked.

```
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'none'", 'https://example.com')
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'" )
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'" )
CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'" )
CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'" )
```

Here is the configuration : Django + REST Framework + React

Thanks a lot!

Comment: it's kind of unclear what you mean. how are you adding the iframe to the page?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. My website is https://www.mywebsite.com and I want to add an iframe  <iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com"> </iframe> on an other website which is https://www.example.com

Comment: You may need to set `X-Frame-Options`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/clickjacking/#how-to-use-it I don't think it's deprecated.

Comment: Yes but only two options are available: SAMEORIGIN or DENY. Which means that I can't "open" to an other URL with it

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS policy setting. Update the tuple to include "https://example.com" which is the hostname of your REACT frontend.

```
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS=["https://example.com"]
```

This policy setting does not use default-src as a fallback which is the reason why your configuration did not allow for iframing.